# Namespacing multiple events using jquery "on"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering what the correct method to namespace multiple events using jquery "on" ...

**for example:**

```
$(".parent-selector").on({
"mouseenter.namespace": function() {
    // mouseenter event
},
"mouseleave.namespace": function() {
    // mouseleave event
}
}, ".selector");
```

This is not working... If i remove the ".namespace" it does work.

**Example of jquery on with working namespace:**

```
$(".parent-selector").on("mouseenter.namespace", ".selector", function() { });
```

I understand I can do both the mouseenter/mouseleave events seprately ... just curious if there is a way to pass namespaces through the object

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the source, that should work...

Comment: Your code works as-is. http://jsfiddle.net/GHmaE/

Comment: My code does work perfectly as is... my problem was that I had another namespace conflict. =/ Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To attach to multiple events you have to pass a space separated list of events:

```
$(".parent-selector").on("mouseenter.namespace mouseleave.namespace",
                         ".selector", function() { });
```

**Edit:**

You can always get the type of event inside the callback and call other functions inside:

```
$(".parent-selector").on("mouseenter.namespace mouseleave.namespace", ".selector", function(e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseenter.namespace") {
        myMouseEnter(e);
    } else if (e.type == "mouseleave.namespace") {
        myMouseLeave(e);
    }
});
```

Althrough it seems to work, I can't confirm that, cause I'm not on my machine. Give it a try.

Comment: yes, this works.. however i need a different function for each event

Comment: If you need a different function, why are you combining them?

Comment: emulating "hover" with jquery "on". mouseenter has one function, mouseleave has anther. the reason i'm combining them is so I dont have to declare the parent selector / event selector twice. Just trying to keep it wrapped nicely

Comment: I've edited to add an example.

Comment: Are you attaching this to dynamic generated content? If not, you can use `.hover(function(e){}, function(e){})`.

Comment: bleh, i got it working... the code was fine as-is. I had a conflict with an event earlier in the code binding to the same namespace.

Answer (score 3):

The Below code is actually correct -- I had an issue with namespacing conflict earlier in the code.

```
$(".parent-selector").on({
    "mouseenter.namespace": function() {
        // mouseenter event
    },
    "mouseleave.namespace": function() {
        // mouseleave event
    }
}, ".selector");
```

Comment: Normally you would edit the original question to add this info.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said in a comment, you want to fire a different function for each namespace. Seems weird you would combine them to want to do something different. But if you want to know what triggered the event, you can use [`event.type`](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/).

```
$("#foo").on("mouseover mouseout", ".bar",
    function(evt){
       console.log(evt.type); 
    }
);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5W5Qg/)

Comment: It's no more weird than doing it with (now removed) .hover method in my opinion. I'd prefer just using two separate handlers than adding more logic.

Comment: @KevinB, hence why hover was removed. lol